# Unity3D getting errors without console - android build

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, console

I want to check exceptions and errors in my game in built up, but there is no debug console in game so I want to make one. Is there any way to get those errors from original console and write it on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a callback function to `Application.logMessageReceived` to receive the Debug.* messages. For example:

```
void Awake(){
    Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
} 


private void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type) {
    // add them to some UI component for visualizing
}
```

Comment: How can I print it now?
What is stackTrace?

Comment: A stacktrace is a register of which method was executing (and where it was called from) at the moment of the exception (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace). If you are asking that, I suggest you check some programming books or online resources, and learn this and other basic concepts, as you will surely need them. As for showing the error, I think @fafase suggested a way already. Create a GUI element with text and append to it.